# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority [ ngrok ]

Tags: ngrok

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
Session Status                reconnecting (x509: certificate signed by unknown authority)
Version                       2.3.35
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

```
ngrok location : c/ngrok.exe 
operating system: windows 10 (64bit)
localhost: xampp (apache)
ngrok config: C:\Users\Anuruddha\.ngrok2\ngrok.yaml
```

inside ngrok.yaml I have my auth key as well.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this? I assume you're also behind a corporate proxy?

Answer (score 4):

You can try these solutions:

1. Use version **2.2.8** instead, it can be found on https://dl.equinox.io/ngrok/ngrok/stable/archive.
   There are some minor bugs from version 2.3.x and above.
2. Add **root_cas: trusted** to your ngrok.yaml file.
3. Change to other regions.
4. If you are using VPN, stop using VPN, create ngrok tunnel first, then connect to VPN.
5. If you are using Proxy Server, make sure you have these settings in your yaml file:

   - **http_proxy: true**
   - **inspect_db_size: 50000000**

> https://ngrok.com/docs#config

Comment: Note that Ngrok is now at version 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Also check you firewall and domain network blocking tools!